# can't install latest nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm trying to install the latest x-swat nvidia drivers. I follow the process described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/104534/73080).

It seems to work ok, i.e. my repository shows the right version (304.43), but when I load the Nvidia X Server Settings application it still shows `Nvidia Driver Version: 295.49`

I tried purging, rebooting, reinstalling. Nothing seems to make an effect (at least on the Nvidia X Server Settings app).

Any suggestion why this is happening or how to wipe the driver and install the latest one?

Answer (score 0):

Strange to say, I have the same problem with a GT440. After install and reboot, the old 295 driver is still present and current.
Any idea ?

giuliano@saturn:~$ uname -a

Linux saturn 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:03:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updatese

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

sudo shutdown -r now

giuliano@saturn:~$ nvidia-settings -v

nvidia-settings:  version 295.33  (buildd@allspice)  Fri Mar 30 15:25:24 UTC 2012
  The NVIDIA X Server Settings tool.

giuliano@saturn:~$ nvidia-settings  -q GPUs

1 GPU on saturn:0

```
[0] saturn:0[gpu:0] (GeForce GT 440)
```