# How can I install proprietary drivers/repo via the command line in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

What do I have to do via the command line, in order to achieve exactly the same thing that the "Software & Updates" graphical application does? Namely, enable a NVIDIA driver repository and then install it.

The reason I want to do this is because the progress bar of my "Software & Updates" is stuck at 1/3 for like forever and I don't know how to debug what's wrong.

Comment: Do the following and add to your question what it errors out: "sudo apt-get update". If nothing bad happens type "sudo apt-get install nvidia-current" and add to the question anything it errors out.

Answer (score 0):

The operations described on this page modify the software repositories configuration file located at 
/etc/apt/sources.list

However the drivers aren't exactly in a repo like you are thinking.
Check the out for more [How do I install the latest Nvidia drivers via the Additional Drivers tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104527/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-via-the-additional-drivers-tool)