# Every time I get an update that says "Ubuntu Base" I lose graphics, and have to reinstall the driver. Is there a fix?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a 64 bit Intel box with a GeForce GTX 750 Ti (used for gaming on my Windows partition).

Every time I get an update to Ubuntu Base, I lose graphics. The only way I've figured out how to fix it is to boot into safe mode, drop into a root prompt, and run the NVIDIA driver installer.

It wasn't just a one-time thing; it's been probably the past 5-6 updates.

I'd imagine this perhaps has something to do with X settings, but I'm not completely sure. Is there some way I can make this automated (a script that perhaps fixes whatever settings get messed up)?

Or, perhaps, is this a bug that the community should be made aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing you can try that could be quicker is that when it reboots after the Ubuntu Base which is probably the kernel update, is to boot into Recovery Mode with `root`.  Mount the partition in Read/Write: `mount -o remount,rw /` then go to the `/usr/src/nvidia-xxx.xx/` folder and run `make` from there to reinstall only the kernel driver for the video itself, instead of reinstalling the full driver each time.

Comment: @Terrance, thanks! I can at minimum write a script for myself to do that so it's not such a pain every time.

Any idea why this happens? Is it a bug or expected behavior?

Comment: You're welcome!  I believe it is the drivers from the NVIDIA site themselves are not getting copied over into the new kernel.  I have found if I use the drivers from the `Additional Drivers` in Ubuntu, they seem to copy OK into the new kernel.

Comment: But I have had to do that with having 340.76 drivers from NVIDIA by running `make` to put them back in the kernel.

Comment: How can I set it up to use the drivers from Ubuntu? Mine doesn't seem to have anything available:  http://imgur.com/oF1OUYj

Comment: Looks like the GeForce GTX 750 Ti is not on the official supported list.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsNvidia

Comment: You need to install them this way, not manually: https://askubuntu.com/questions/104527/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-via-the-additional-drivers-tool

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have installed the package called **dkms**. After that, when you run the nvidia installer, it will ask you whether you want to register with DKMS. Tell it to do so.

Next time when a kernel update happens, it will recompile the shim code automatically.

The only thing you need to watch out for are MESA updates. Those tend to clobber the OpenGL setup. It's fixed by re-running the installer. I'm currently waiting to see if step **no. 10** of [this tutorial](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=184126) fixes the problem permanently. I don't care about MESA, I do not intend to run the open-source driver anyway.